# Dual-booting Seagate Momentus XT Solid State Hybrid Drive

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, hybrid-storage

Is it possible to gain the speed benefits of a hybrid SSD/HDD with a partition of Max OS X (say Leopard or Snow Leopard) and Windows 7 (running on Bootcamp)? Considering getting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, partition structure doesn't matter.  It will partition the disk itself.  The flash storage portion will work for both partitions.

Comment: That's what I expected. It sounds like it's designed to move arbitrary pieces dynamically, to and from the SSD as needed.